# Sphinx change cron indexing to real time

Tags: sphinx

I want to change Sphinx indexing to real-time. But I always have this error when trying to execute my search query.

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
index serv1: parse error: unknown column: post_category_name
```

Even if I try this query I have empty result set and it's not valid info :

```
select * from serv1
```

Without this config evrything works fine:

```
    type = rt
    rt_field = title
    rt_field = description
    rt_field = post_category_name
```

My sphinx.conf is:

```
source src1 
{
  type          = mysql

  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = root
  sql_pass      = root
  sql_db        = serv
  sql_port      = 3306

    sql_query = select  p.id,  p.title, p.description, l.Latitude as latitude, $
     FROM post p join location l on l.id = p.location_id \
    left join post_category pc on pc.post_id=p.id GROUP BY p.id  ORDER BY NULL

    sql_attr_float = latitude
    sql_attr_float = longitude
    sql_field_string = title
    sql_field_string = description
    sql_field_string = post_category_name
}
index serv1
{
    type = rt
    rt_field = title
    rt_field = description
    rt_field = post_category_name

 source            = src1
  path              = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
  docinfo           = extern
  morphology = stem_en

}
searchd
{
  listen            = 9306:mysql41
  log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
  mysql_version_string = 5.0.37
}
```

My search query:

```
select id, post_category_name , title, description,
WEIGHT()from serv1 where match('@(title,description) site  
@post_category_name ALL | THERAPEUTIC') LIMIT 0 , 30 OPTION 
ranker=expr('sum(hit_count*user_weight)'),field_weights= 
 (title=3,body=1);
```

Please help me find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that specifying a source in a real-time index is not supported. You can either specify a source in a plain index and then rebuild it with help of 'indexer' or just configure a real-time index and then INSERT into it or [ATTACH](https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/sphinxql_reference/attach_index_syntax.html) a plain index to the real-time index.

But the error you get should have another reason. Perhaps you modified the config and added the new attribute, but your RT index doesn't know about that. In this case try to:

- stop your searchd
- remove your RT index by removing all its files- /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1*
- start the searchd back

Comment: I removed "source" , added  to config:  rt_attr_string = post_category_name
      rt_attr_string = title
      rt_attr_string = description
      path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test4 
.Now query executes but I have empty result set((

Comment: Do I need also insert date to index?

Comment: I need some solution for updating my serv1 index after some changing in DB, can you hint me easy solution for this?

Comment: RT indexes are very different. They dont use 'indexer'. To update them, issue sphinxQL queries (`INSERT INTO rtindex ... `) - the idea being the application can issue the inserts as and when new data is available. (ie the process that inserts data into mysql, should insert a 'copy' into sphinx at the same time) ... you may need to code your own 'batch insert' process, so initially **fill** the index (or use ATTACH as mentoned)